How could I setup the db2 client in the php:apache docker image?
I am trying to make an image for my PHP to connecting with the IBM db2 DB.
But I tried to make my own Dockerfile and it always failed, here's the one:
FROM php:apache

ADD /v11.5.4_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar.gz /opt/ibm/

RUN export IBM_DB_HOME=/opt/ibm/dsdriver && \
    apt-get update && apt-get -y install ksh zip && \
    ksh /opt/ibm/dsdriver/installDSDriver && \
    env IBM_DB_HOME=/opt/ibm/dsdriver && \
    pecl install ibm_db2 && \
    echo "extension=ibm_db2.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ibm_db2.ini

RUN apt-get update

at the middle, I tried to install the php-pear or pkg-php-tools, but it always displayed the php-pear cannot be installed.
Is anyone tried and success before? Is it possible to share your solution here? Many thanks!
